# Text Position In Python Shell

Tags: python, shell, text, position

I'm looking to make a game in python's Shell. However, when text is printed, it is printed at the bottom. Is there any code I can use to scroll it all to the top or indent it. Please let me know! I'll show an example of what I want to happen:

The code sections are the Shell screens

**EDIT**
This 'Hello Welcome' is printed at the top of the Shell screen

```
                        Hello                        
                       Welcome!
```

This is an example for a UI, the text is indented:

```
            Money: $5
```

The text is indented

I also want to select a line to print the text eg:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

print 'Hi' line 2
```

If anyone knows how to do this please let me know, I've looked for some time and haven't found any answer.

Comment: you can use control characters such as `\r` but I don't think there is a way to directly specify the line.

Comment: I want to be able to specify a line or atleast be able to scroll the python shell screen with code

Comment: `"{:*>30}".format("hello")` will print `*************hello`, 30 chars in total, right aligned, with a fill *.

Comment: Use https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.center to center align the text. not sure how to make it align vertically, that could be solved by a few cleverly timed newlines I suppose.

Comment: Looking at things like ncurses may be useful here.

Comment: Thanks. Anyone know how to make it scroll up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use formatting for indentation

   ```
   print('            %s' % 'hello')
   >>>            hello
   ```
2. The perfect solution and, as I know common for console apps: clean output and reprint it with updated state